# IBM installation manager 1.8.4 cannot find any packages to install

Tags: ibm-installation-manager

I’m installing the Websphere Fix pack 8.5.5.12 in our Redhat Linux 6 environment using IBM Installation Manager 1.8.4.

I can start IM and add the repository using the typical steps but for some reason its not picking it up.

I add the repository as follows via the preferences,

/rational/rational/Was855_FP012/

I save the changes and the repository shows but when I go back to the main IM window and hit 1. to install I get,

> IBM installation manager 1.8.4 cannot find any packages to install

This directory includes the repository.config file as part of extract of all 3 files
8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP012-part1.zip
8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP012-part2.zip
8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP012-part3.zip

previously we installed the WAS85511 patch using the same method and installed successfully

Also the user owns both the installation manager folder and the repository folders.

Environment details:
IBM Installation Manager
Version: 1.8.4
Internal version: 1.8.4000.20151125_0201
Architecture: 64-bit

WAS FP downloads:
8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP012-part1.zip
8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP012-part2.zip
8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP012-part3.zip

Redhat Linux 6

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was installing from the wrong installation manager instance /rational/imcl-1.8.4/tools/imcl

Had to run from the IM which installed the original Websphere instance and Fix packs.

using /app/IBM/IM/eclipse/tools/

```
 ./imcl -c
```

Also instead of using option 1. to install.  Must use option 2. to UPDATE for this particular package.

for certain versions of Websphere you must use a silent install or command line install to install the package and bypass the interactive mode.

For 8.5.5.11 we had to run

```
 /app/IBM/IM/eclipse/tools/./imcl install 
 com.ibm.websphere.ND.v85_8.5.5012.20170627_1018 -repositories 
 /rational/Was855_FP012 -installationDirectory /app/IBM/WAS85 -
 acceptLicense -sP
```

which translates to 
    /app/IBM/YourIMInstall/./imcl install 
    com.ibm.websphere.ND.v85_8.5.5012.20170627_1018 -repositories 
    /yourRepolocation -installationDirectory /yourWASInstallPath/ 
    acceptLicense -sP

After the installation completes run the following command to confirm the update

```
/app/IBM/WAS85/bin/./versionInfo.sh

[appadm@myServer bin]$ ./versionInfo.sh
WVER0010I: Copyright (c) IBM Corporation 2002, 2012; All rights 
reserved.
WVER0012I: VersionInfo reporter version 1.15.1.49, dated 4/7/17
```